# Should I restart the git repository on breaking technological change?

Tags: git, project, project-structure

If I change the framework or one of the major technology (for example React -> Vue) should I restart the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by restart you mean reset the commit history, you should probably not.

If you delete your commit history you won't be able to revert or rollback your breaking changes. So it is better to keep it in your repository or work in a new repository.